# Is it possible to start / stop apache service from PHP?

Tags: php, apache, service

I have created a simple website that will help me in my many projects by creating a sub domain for each new website project that I take on.

I keep going back to the older websites I've created so I have decided to keep all of them as a sub domain on localhost.

My PHP code works fine to add the information to the relevant files.

But I need to restart Apache for the changes to take affect.
I know PHP runs from the Apache service. Is it possible therefor to stop and start or even restart the Apache service from PHP code?

Comment: Yes I suppose you can with `exec()` or `shell_exec()`, note you need root access.

Comment: A restart would be possible by using an external command like (in Slackware Linux:   `/etc/rc.d/rc.httpd restart`). Mind - it might stop your PHP script too, if you are executing through the server.

Comment: Apache also has a `reload` command that just tells it to reload the configuration without a stop/start. That might work for most of this stuff. `service apache2 reload`. Also, if this is about hosting sub-domains, have a look at the [mod_vhost_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html) module. It allows you to map the hostname to directories by pattern. I used to have mine setup with a wildcard dns entry (all sub to same IP) and then map `whatever.test.com` to `/var/www/whatever` so any subdomain mapped to it's own folder. Adding a sub was as easy as creating a folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, with `exec()`

```
exec("apachectl restart");
```

You might want to allow programs to close themselves before just shutting down the server, so I'd recommend:

```
exec("apachectl graceful");
```

Make sure PHP doesn't run in [safemode](http://php.net/manual/de/features.safe-mode.php) (<= PHP 5.3), as these functions won't be available then.

Please note, this is how I restart apache on my server, you might have to adjust the command.

Also think about the permissions. Not all users (and probably not the one running php scripts) have permission to stop the server.

Comment: thank you so much! `apachectl graceful-stop` was what I needed :D